# Use selected option values for asp-route in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, tag-helpers

I want to have two select forms that pass their selected values to the URL via a GET request.

Can I do this with only Tag Helpers? Or do I need to use JavaScript?

Here is the form code from the view

```
<form asp-action="Index" asp-route-startyear="@selectedValue1" asp-route-endyear="@selectedValue2" method="get">
```

And here is the controller that it is calling

```
public IActionResult Index(int startYear = 1978, int endYear = 0)
```

And finally this is the route from the startup.cs file

```
        routes.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "StandingsByYear",
            pattern: "{startyear:int}/{endyear:int}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

I can make add an `onclick()` to the submit button that changes the `window.location.href` using JavaScript but was wondering if there was in Tag Helper magic that could pull off the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag Helpers enable server-side code to participate in creating and rendering HTML elements . So that if you want to bind client side value(from select) , tag helper won't work and you need to dynamically change the url in Javascript .